# boostrap navbar button toggle not working

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[noob alert] I am using bootstrap 3 alongside with a bought theme. When using on smaller viewport size, the nav button doesn't work. Which part of it am I missing? Thanks a lot!

```
<header class="page-header">
  <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="navbar-header">

      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </button>

      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello World!</a>
      </div>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">That</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">This</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: If I am right you should use also an responsive css file from css folder.

Comment: Does the Nav bar even show up? Can you reproduce this on bootply.com

Comment: I tried this in bootply.com and it worked indeed. Would it be the bought theme that is blocking this? What is the inbuilt bootstrap css code that power the collapsed nav behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

i works on me, maybe you forgot to add the jquery, script
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: is the jquery part of the dependencies of using bootstrap?

Comment: yup, for the js part of bootstrap